Valid Parentheses using stack in C gives correct answer locally but fails on LeetCode
I'm attempting to solve Valid Parentheses problem in leetcode. The following code passes the tests on my local machine yet fails when run on leetcode. (Specifically it fails on "{[]}" )
This is the code in leetcode:
typedef struct Stack{
    int size;
    int free;
    char *buff;
    char *top;
}Stack; 

Stack stack = {
    .size = 0,
    .free = 0,
    .buff = NULL,
    .top = NULL
}; 
void push(char c){
    if (stack.free == 0){
        stack.buff = realloc(stack.buff, stack.size + 10);
        if (stack.size == 0) stack.top = stack.buff;
        stack.size+=10;
        stack.free+=10;
    }
    *(stack.top) = c; 
    --(stack.free);
    
    if (stack.free > 0)
        ++(stack.top);
}
char pull(){
    if (stack.free > 0){
        char tmp = *(stack.top - 1);
        if (stack.top != stack.buff){
            --(stack.top);
        }
        ++stack.free;
        return tmp;
    }else if (stack.free == 0){
        return *(stack.top);
    }
    return -1;
}

char top(){
    if (stack.size == 0) return -1;
    return (stack.free > 0) ? *(stack.top - 1) : *(stack.top);
}

//vs enum!!
#define OP '(' //open paranthesis 
#define CP ')' //closed paranthesis
#define OB '['
#define CB ']'
#define OC '{'
#define CC '}'

bool isCorrectChar(char expected_ch){
    if (top() == expected_ch){
        pull();
        return true;
    }else{
        return false; 
    } 
}

bool isValid(char* s) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    if (len%2 != 0) return false;
    char expected_ch; 
    char c;
    while ((c = *s++) != '\0'){
        switch (c){
            //push open punctuation to stack
            case OP:
            case OB:
            case OC:
                push(c);
                break;
            //pull closed punctuation from stack
            case CP:
                expected_ch = OP; 
                if (isCorrectChar(expected_ch) == false) return false;
                break;
            case CB:
                expected_ch = OB;
                if (isCorrectChar(expected_ch) == false) return false;
                break;
            case CC:
                expected_ch = OC;
                if (isCorrectChar(expected_ch) == false) return false;
                break;
            default: // illegal character found...
                return false;
        }// end of switch 
    }
    if (stack.free == stack.size)
        return true;
    return false;
}

To practice locally I have these additional statements:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("%s: %s\n", argv[1], isValid(argv[1]) ? "true": "false");
    return 0;
}

It gave the correct result for all the tests I threw at it. including "(())", "{[]}", "({{}})", "()()"
I copied the code in leetcode except the main function and includes. I expected to get the same results as I did in my local machine. The test failed on leetcode.

The only nice thing I know about Leetcode is that it shows you the failing test-case. That means you could hard-code it into your main function, and use a debugger to step through the code to see what's wrong.

if (stack.size == 0) stack.top = stack.buff; -- and if the stack size is not zero, what should stack.top be? You have to update it because the old pointer is invalid because it got realloc'd away.

The realloc may invalidate stack.top, and that your logic depends on whether the stack is currently full or not is most likely not correct (it should only matter when deciding whether to reallocate).

if (stack.free > 0)  ++(stack.top); you now have an inconsistency between a full stack (where the top element is at *top) and a not-full stack (where the top element is at *(top - 1)), which pull does not take into account properly.

It can be the case that, because its behavior is undefined or parts of it are implementation-specific, a program behaves differently on one C implementation than on another.  If you expect it to work the same everywhere then this is a flaw in the program, not, usually, a failing of either C implementation.  But with coding challenges, "it works locally but the automated judge fails it" usually means that the automated judge fed your program a valid test case that it did not handle successfully.  Often such cases test the extremes of the defined input constraints.

A trivial change to (likely) pass Leetcode would be to start the first allocation with 10000 instead of only 10... @RaymondChen (likely) hit-the-nail-on-the-head pointing out that the code doesn't account for a different flavour of realloc() that relocates the heap buffer when growing the buffer. (stack.top remains pointing to the old block of heap, then writes outside that block corrupting memory.) You can pass this challenge simply, or you can fix the code to make it correct and reliable.
